# Xamarin.iOS Push notifications from Azure Notification Hub

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to add push notifications to my Xamarin.iOS app using this tutorial 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started

I have followed all the steps as it is and below is what I have tried so far :-

AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
  {
   // create a new window instance based on the screen size
   Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
   if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
   {
    var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
        UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
        new NSSet());

    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
   }
   else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
   }


   // If you have defined a root view controller, set it here:
   UIStoryboard storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
   var myViewController = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("Login_VC") as LoginViewController;
   Window.RootViewController = myViewController;

   // make the window visible
   Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();



   return true;
  }

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
  {
   Hub = new SBNotificationHub(ServiceConstants.ListenConnectionString, ServiceConstants.NotificationHubName);

   string token = deviceToken.ToString().Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace(" ", "");

   deviceToken = NSData.FromString(token);
   Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) =>
   {
    if (error != null)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
     return;
    }

    NSSet tags = null; // create tags if you want
    Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
    {
     if (errorCallback != null)
      Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
    });
   });




  }
```

I have signed my app with a development provisioning profile from the apple developer console which is signed with an AppId with Push notifications enabled on it.

But when I get an error at the very beginning while registering for push notifications as follows :-

```
  Error Response:<Error><Code>401</Code><Detail>ExpiredToken: .TrackingId:94e8c47b-1221-4188-8a75-9b744e12c9d7_G4,TimeStamp:1/20/2017 10:05:51 AM</Detail></Error>
Fail to perform registration operation.
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x170018a70> { URL: https://mynotificationnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/mynotificationhub/Registrations/?$filter=deviceToken+eq+'62383062663335386437646233313263613766656165323535626634646537393438623262616238393164393466393766353030666166313966623339323232'&api-version=2013-04 }
 Headers:{
    Authorization = "SharedAccessSignature sr=http%3a%2f%2fmynotificationnamespace.servicebus.windows.net%2fmynotificationhub%2fregistrations%2f%3f%24filter%3ddevicetoken%2beq%2b%2762383062663335386437646233313263613766656165323535626634646537393438623262616238393164393466393766353030666166313966623339323232%27%26api-version%3d2013-04&sig=dpGnfYj19D%2FseR3GlTrE6Ay0ASdc%2BwFwWRNf3sxBE0%3D&se=148394919&skn=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature";
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
    "User-Agent" = "NOTIFICATIONHUBS/2013-04(api-origin=IosSdk; os=iOS; os_version=10.2;)";
}
```

I am able to get the Push notifications working from the same Notification hub for Xamarin.Android but not Xamarin.iOS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question as it might be useful for people looking for something similar. Turns out the Automatic DateTime was disabled on my device hence the device token was fetching as invalid or expired as the time on the device was lagging behind with 30 mins.